# Is there any package manager for BLFS?

Tags: package-management, lfs

I have successfully installed BLFS 8.4 and now I want to install a package manager to keep my system up to date. I want to know if it's possible and how.

Comment: http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/8.4/chapter06/pkgmgt.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now you could integrate an existing package manager like apt into the LFS build but it is highly unreliable as you are likely to end up in dependency hell very fast and it is a very lengthy process to set up a package manager and no one has ever successfully been able to integrate a package manager to an LFS system. The only other solution you have is creating your own package manager which is a whole new level of complicated altogether. There is a hint though which explains  how to install dpkg and apt to LFS at http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/hints/downloads/files/dpkg.txt

Answer (score 4):

I partly agree with the other answer from Sai Maanas music, but disagree on the "no one has ever successfully" there are at least 14 package management programs or methods that apparently seem to work. some do require early integration, hence the early mention of package management in the LFS book.

for general package management RPM, Deb and arch PKGBUILD (and maybe more) there are plenty more hints in the linked https://www.linuxfromscratch.org/hints/downloads/files/ site. Many other projects exist and are used often by some users successfully. one of these is https://github.com/KeithDHedger/LFSPkg/

The biggest issue you might face is the existence of files already installed and a future package manager unaware of their existence. https://www.linuxfromscratch.org/hints/downloads/files/dpkg.txt as already hinted to, also includes a way to make the manager be aware of these packages by preloading the database (its just a text file) with said "packages". For other package types, you might need to look into how they store these details and alter their databases accordingly. simple rpm/dep installing works and uninstalling or updating might work.

Dependency resolving and hinting is another beast however and I've read and seen people have success with Arch Linux pacman and their AUR PKGBUILD system. You might not want to copy their mirrors however if you don't want to break your system or turn it into Arch slowly over its update/upgrade life. Its definitely not impossible to get a or multiple package managers to work, and some people even made compile servers and mirror systems for their personal network. I hope https://www.linuxfromscratch.org/hints/downloads/files/rpm.txt for rpm packages and a look at https://github.com/benvd/lfs-pacman gives you enough inspiration to try and test these. maybe not on your daily driver, a VM or temp system might be the best

Answer (score 1):

While I agree it may be beyond the scope of the core LFS book and possibly BLFS, The Linux Standards Base specifies the rpm format as the "standard" package management style.